# Is there a way to add a mixin into a variable in LESS

Tags: variables, less, mixins

Can I add a mixin to a variable in LESS?

Something like this

```
@input-border-radius: .rounded();
or
@h1: .font-size(46) // This pulls from the rem calculator mixin.
```

Looked at the LESS Docs but can't see a way to do it.

Comment: In short, no, you can't directly assign a mixin to a variable. However there's so called ["detached ruleset"](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) feature introduced in Less 1.7.0, so it *is* possible to do this indirectly, e.g.: `@input-border-radius: {.rounded()};` and `@h1: {.font-size(46)};` (the rest depends on how you're going to actually use these variables).

Comment: Seven-phases-max, how new is this, because I'm getting an error on save as build in sublime text

Comment: [Less 1.7.0](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#170).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way.

You can define properties of a (possibly immaginary) class and recall the properties of that class in the style of a different class. For example:

```
.fontstyling {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: black;
}

h1 {
   font-size: 46px;
   .fontstyling;
}

h2 {
   font-size: 38px;
   .fontstyling;
}
```

(thats not the best way to format the headings - but for other exemples it is really useful!)

Comment: thanks, but I'm using a REM Mixin which calculates px and turns it into rem's, so this wouldn't work for me.